# Font Book does not Install all fonts

Tags: macos, leopard, font, font-book

My Mac decided to delete all but 19 fonts, which is fairly annoying. It didn't really delete them, as in I still have the original files in the `/Library/Fonts` folder, but they've disappeared from Font Book, so I can't use them.

Now, Apple says that you can select a folder to install *all* fonts in that folder, but when I try that, the spinning wheel (not the beach ball) comes up in the lower right hand corner for a few seconds and then leaves, without installing any fonts. The same thing happens if I use the `+` sign in the menu bar, select multiple, or if I try validating and then installing (actually, that installs one font).

Is there any way to mass-install these fonts or will I have to install them one by one?

System info: Mac OS X 10.5.8 running Font Book 2.1 (123).

Answer (score 2):

I'll bet you have a font corruption problem.

1. Split the uninstalled fonts into two groups.
2. Import the first group.
3. Check to see if they imported successfully.

   - If yes, you know the problem is in the second group, so go to step #1.
   - If no, the second group might be okay, so try importing that.

And so on.

You should be able to narrow down the problem without having to import each font one at a time. But my guess is that one or more of your fonts is corrupted.

Comment: That's thinking like a programmer ;o)